# CORS vulnerability or secure?

Tags: cors

Testing a website i am in this scenario, i found a CORS endpoint that allows any subdomains to access it, so for example:

Real request:

```
Origin: https://abc.realwebsite.com   --->
access-control-allow-origin: https://abc.realwebsite.com
```

but as it accepts every subdomain i am able to change it like this:

Modified request:

```
Origin: https:/mywebsite.com/hey.realwebsite.com   --->
access-control-allow-origin: https:/mywebsite.com/hey.realwebsite.com
```

Is it possible to exploit this? How would the origin header handle a directory instead of a domain? How can i reproduce this to make a proof that it is exploitable.

Comment: *"How can i reproduce this to make a proof that it is exploitable."* - likely you can't. The browser sets the Origin header to only the domain and you cannot change this. And outside the browser CORS is irrelevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing: unless the CORS headers also allow credentials or are on a server that isn't supposed to be accessible from arbitrary IP addresses (or returns different content depending on the request source), this isn't really a vulnerability at all. If the browser cannot make authenticated requests (or at least not see the responses), then it can't do anything that the attacker couldn't do by just using `curl` on their own computer.

Next, the Origin header is only controlled by the browser, not the user. An attacker cannot cause a request to be sent with a custom origin, nor is there any circumstance where the browser would send an origin containing a path (protocol, port (if non-default), and domain only). As such, the server *properly* ought to be rejecting your requests as invalid, but what you've demonstrated is not exploitable in any way.